# Responsive Printing

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a receipt that scales to the browser width nicely use css media queries. When it comes time to print on 72mm paper, it only prints about half of it and the rest is cut off.

Do I need to do special css media queries so when printing it scales down? I couldn't find a lot of information about responsive printing. I understand responsive design, but I figured it out carry over to printing.

Comment: the answer lies in your code or maybe it does not yet to figure that out we'd need at least some

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! 72 mm is 216 pixels and when I sized it down to that width there was a problem.